# How to parallelise nested for loops in python

Tags: python, joblib, multiprocessor

I have this function containing nested loops. I need to parallelise for faster execution of code.

```
def euclid_distance(X,BOW_X):
     d3=[]
     d2=[]

     for l in range(len(X)):
         for n in range(l+1,len(X)):
             d1=[]
             for m in range(len(X[l])):
                 min1=999
                 p=0
                 while(p<len(X[n])):
                     d=scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean(X[l][m],X[n][p])
                     d=d*numpy.min([BOW_X[l][m],BOW_X[n][p]])
                     if(d<min1):
                         min1=d
                     if(min1==0):
                         break
                     p+=1
                 d1.append(min1)

             d2.append(d1)

     for i in range(len(d2)):
         d3.append(sum(d2[i]))


return (d3)
```

Is there some way to do this
X is an array containing list of lists which contain vectors.

Comment: can you give a small example of what is X, BOW_X, C, and expected output?

Comment: X=array( [ [[1,2,3],[2,7,6],[3,0,1]],[[3,3,3],[1,1,1]],[[6,7,5],[9,0,1],[3,7,5],[0,4,4]] ], dtype=object)

Description : [1,2,3] --> vector rep of a word
[1,2,3],[2,7,6],[3,0,1]] --> document containing 3 words
so the array contains 3 documents with 3, 2, 4 words resp

BOW_X=array( [ [[0.1,0.02,0.3],[0.2,0.7,0.6],[0.03,0,0.1]],[[0.03,0.3,0.03],[0.1,0.1,0.1]],[[0.6,0.7,0.5],[0.9,0,0.01],[0.3,0.7,0.5],[0,0.4,0.04]] ], dtype=object)

Output : I want to calculate minimum distance of each word in one doc from each word of other doc, store the min. and then add them to get dist b/w 2 docs

Comment: Revert back in case of clarification required

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using xrange instead of range? it may help for faster execution.
(this should be in the comment but i have not yet unlocked it, sorry)

Comment: That won't help much, as i have huge dataset. I need a way to parallelise it using joblib library

Answer (score 0):

You may use PyCuda if you have a GPU and there is no data dependency between the instructions. With PyCuda you can spawn multiple parallel threads but there will be some overheads for data transfer between the devices, i.e., CPU and GPU.